# Azure Database Columns not show up in SQL Management Studio 2014

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have an azure database and when I connect with SQL Management Studio 2014 the columns for the databases do not appear and I'm not able to query any tables.

But if I connect to the same azure database with Visual Studio 2013 or SQL Server 2016 CTP2 Management Studio everything works fine.

This is a bug in SQL Management Studio 2014?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that was a limitation by design. And it bothered a lot of people.

But right now, I found an article which shows that Microsoft might have finally changed something!! Hey, that sounds great! I will try it later and post it.

In the meanwhile, here is the link to the Microsoft article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-2014-management-studio-updated-support-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Seems that SQL Server Client Connectivity Tools isn't properly installed.

Installing latest version of service pack for SQL Server 2014 could help you.

You could find it http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/